# Domain integration - Is there any special setup for the farm

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, active-directory, domain, trusted-domain

We recently got merged with another company. Our company intranet is inside.go2.com (multi server sp 2010 farm). Say our domain is SilverForest and we have multple SP 2010 farms (Prod, QA and DEV). The domain for the company bought us is GoldForest. Now, the network and server team has been working on the AD trust. I was able to add GoldForest/Domain users to all of SharePoint's site collection. and Now both companies see each other SharePoint site. The SharePoint site will stay separated as we are in 2 different business. I just learned that they are working on Domain Integration and we are going to be under GoldForest.

What are the steps I need to take for our SharePoint 2010 environment to make sure there are not issues after the domain integration?

Will the user profile pictures stay in tack during or post domain integration?

Our current authentication is windows which will stay as is.

Comment: when you merge both both, you will migrate all user /computers etc to GoldForest from silver forest?

Comment: Yes.I think users are going to move to new domain first.

Answer (score 0):

If your Domain is moving / becoming GoldForest then its not easy to keep your environment up and running. In real ideal situation is you have to rebuild the farm.

In this Blog, he explain all steps by step process to move a server to new domain( which is your case if i understand correct). You choice is limited because you are moving to new forest.

You will need to build a new farm in the target forest (preferably with service accounts in the new forest) and then subsequently migrate accounts. Account migration can be done with ADMT on the domain side, and then within SharePoint you'll need to use Move-SPUser.

http://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2011/09/23/move-sharepoint-2010-server-to-another-domain/